# How do I change page callback for a particular menu?

Tags: 8, routes

There is already a menu defined in core module. I need to alter the page callback of this menu in another module. Similar to using `hook_menu_alter()` in Drupal 7, but since there is no `hook_menu_alter()` in Drupal 8, how do I define another page callback?

Comment: Did you read http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187585/what-is-the-equivalent-of-hook-menu-alter-to-change-a-menu-item-type ?

Comment: In Drupal 8 there aren't anymore page callbacks.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I need to change the permission callback for  a menu. I have created a custom permission. Now i need to call this custom permission for this menu. My custom permission is properly visible on permission list page.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8 You don't have hook_menu and the are changed to "Routers" now.

Drupal 8 has a new menu system, there is no hook_menu and no hook_menu_alter anymore.

If you want to alter an existing route, it is a little bit more complicated in comparison to Drupal 7.

In your module you have to create a class file at YOURMODULE/src/Routing/CLASSNAME.php that extends RouteSubscriberBase:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\YOURMODULE\Routing\RouteSubscriber.
 */

namespace Drupal\YOURMODULE\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Get the route you want to alter
    $route = $collection->get('system.admin_content');

    // alter the route...
  }
}
```

You can take the RouteSubsciber class of the node module as an example.

To let your RouteSubscriber be recognized you also have to create a YOURMODULE.services.yml file in the root of your modules directory:

```
services:
  node.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\YOURMODULE\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

To get a better insight to the new menu system I would recommend the following articles:

D7 to D8 upgrade tutorial: Convert hook_menu() and hook_menu_alter() to Drupal 8 APIs
What Happened to Hook_Menu in Drupal 8?
Edit:  the menu system has a different structure now, which has nothing to do with D7's menu system, so there is no such thing as a menu type anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above answers for pointing me in the right direction, but I think the key part is missing - How to change the page callback! Though D8 might not use the phrase `page callback` we still have page callbacks - the `controller::method` which responds to a request.

**Step 1: Create a route subscriber**

Follow the official Drupal 8 documentation on and [create a Drupal 8 Route Subscriber](https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643) - Paritoshik Paul's answer might help you in this step. Make sure you implement the `alterRoutes()` method and that it is working (you might have to clear cache).

At the end of this step, if you do a `die();` in the `alterRoutes()` method, the code execution should stop at the die when rebuilding cache.

**Step 2: Change the page callback**

Once the `RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes()` is confirmed to be working, you can change the page callback to your custom controller::method like this:

```
protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

  // Change the page callback for Taxonomy Term pages.
  $route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical');
  $route->setDefault('_controller', '\\Drupal\\YOURMODULE\\Controller\\YourController::yourMethod');

}
```

In the above example, I change the callback for a taxonomy term page. Of course, we will have to ensure that `YourController::yourMethod` actually exist. Refer official docs for [how to create a basic controller](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller).

Rebuild your cache and your page callback is changed!