# How to override UserController?

Tags: 8

I need to override the UserController to to change logout redirection, I try thiscode below  to test my new controller but my display test inside doesn't work. :

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyModuleUserController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
  * Constructs a MyModuleUserController object.
  *
  */
  public function __construct() {}

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static();
  }

  /**
  * Logs the current user out.
  *
  * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
  *   A redirection to home page.
  */
  public function logout() {
    user_logout();
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "<h1>test controller</h1>";
    exit(0) //@TODO delete this test
    return $this->redirect('user.login');
  }
}
```

**Path :** my_module/src/Controller/UserControler/MyModuleUserController.php

Comment: You need an event subscriber to override the user module's logout route. There's an example here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187585/what-is-the-equivalent-of-hook-menu-alter-to-change-a-menu-item-type

Comment: I try your suggestion with a new file `routeSubscriber.php` and  :`services:
  my_module.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }` but I'm in the fog to debug that.